# What Filter Categories to make screen capture using Directshow?

Tags: filter, directshow, screen-capture

In msdn Filter Categories, What categories to be chosen to make screen capture video
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375655%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm getting you right. Do you want to know which is the category where video capture filters are in? Then have a look at CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory. Or are you looking for a filter that captures "screenshots"? Because there is no such filter by default but several examples around the net.

Answer (score 0):

uscreencapture puts theirselves under "Video Capture Sources" but I suppose it's arbitrary...